# US state border color not changing in Highmaps

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to achieve the effect of having state borders wider than county borders, as shown [in this example](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/maps/demo/us-counties/).

Apparently the Highcharts.grep method is deprecated, so this is what I did to extract the state borders (in Typescript):

```
var lines = Highcharts.geojson(geojsonMap, 'mapline');

var borderLines = lines
            .filter((line:any) => line.properties['hc-group'] === '__border_lines__');
```

And the chart series:

```
    series = [{
        name: 'unemployment',
        borderWidth: 0.2,
        borderColor: 'white',
        states: {
            hover: {
                color: 'black'
            }
        },
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: false,
        },
        type: 'map',
        data: data,
    }, {
        type: 'mapline',
        name: 'State borders',
        data: borderLines,
        color: 'white',
        shadow: false
    }]
```

Problem is that the lines are not white, they are red and I cannot change the color and/or width. This is the screenshot:

[image]

The lines are there, so they are loaded correctly. How to change the color/width?

## Update: Example after changing lineWidth:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `lineWidth` and `color` properties:

```
series: [..., {
    type: 'mapline',
    color: 'blue',
    lineWidth: 5,
    ...
}]
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4Lnxuam0/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/series.mapline.color

Comment: Please see update, line width worked but changing the color to `blue` does nothing, what could be wrong? Could it be that the borders of the counties are the red lines?

Comment: I found it. The difference between my map and the example is that I have the `map` member in `chart`, and in the example they have `mapData` in series. Look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/Pgschr/9j6yt7f1/